# SIM A9G: +CME ERROR: 53 failure

Tags: gsm, http

I'm using a SIM A9G.  When I send HTTP GET command from the serial monitor, it responds. But, it doesn't work when included in the code.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial myserial(8, 7); // RX: 8, TX:7

void setup()
{
//  Wire.begin(I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Serial.begin(19200);
  myserial.begin(19200);    // 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 74880, 115200
  
//  ET.begin(details(mydata), &Wire);
  Serial.println("JSON Initializing...");
  Serial.println("GPRS Starting..........");

//  myserial.listen();
  myserial.println("AT");
  delay(500);

  myserial.println("AT+CREG=?");     //Check Network regiistration, wait a while
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  myserial.println("AT+CCID");  //Specify the connection type
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  myserial.println("AT+CGATT=1");
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();

  myserial.println("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"web.gprs.mtnnigeria.net\"");//Specify the APN
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(2000);
}
 
void loop()
{
  myserial.println("AT+CGATT=1");
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();

  myserial.println("AT+CGACT=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();

  myserial.println("AT+HTTPGET=\"https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2\"");
  delay(5000);
  ShowSerialData();

  myserial.println("AT+CCLK?");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  delay(3000);
}

 
void ShowSerialData()
{
  while (myserial.available() != 0)
  {
    Serial.write(myserial.read());
    //delay(50);
  }
}
```

The output at the serial monitor is the following:

```
+CGATT:1

OK
AT+CGACT=1,1

OK
E⸮⸮T⸮OZ⸮y:/⸮͵*⸮⸮⸮m/⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮=bar1&foo2=bar2"

+CME ERROR: 53
failure, pelase check your network or certificate!

AT+CCLK?

+CCLK: "21/02/22,18:19:43+01"

OK
```

Comment: start with the Arduino software serial example sketch

Comment: A9G Module also support https request ...Due to some other reason , you are getting that error ... Bcz, i tried same server to get the data , is working fine ..

Comment: For me HTTPS working for first 7 or 8 times after that it fails.. @sumit chatterjee for you it works continuously?

Answer (score 1):

You must use this sequence.

AT+CREG=?
AT+CCID
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","ba.amx"
AT+CGACT=1,1

Comment: Some explanation as to why might be helpful.

Comment: i can confirm that  it works. I tested with my Maduino that didn't connect to server and didn't send HTTP get request.